# Highcharts - javascript function on event click gives error e.call is not a function

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock 5.0.7. I my chart options are stored in DB and i am fetching it to get the charts plotted. I need to call some ajax function on click of stacked column chart. The stacked column chart shows properly, but the problem is , when i click on the stack, i get an JS error saying e.call is not a function. Below is the JS error.

```
 highstock.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: e.call is not a function
a.fireEvent @ highstock.js:29
E.firePointEvent @ highstock.js:271
a.Pointer.onContainerClick @ highstock.js:209
    l.onclick @     highstock.js:210
```

The chart options where the javascript is written under plotOption->Series->points->events->click

```
"chart": {
    "type": "column"
},
"credits" :  {
    "enabled" : false
},
"title" :  {
    "text" : "chartName"
},         
"xAxis": {
    "categories": []
},
"yAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "stackLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "style": {
            "fontWeight": "bold",
            "color": "gray"

        }
    }
},
"legend": {
    "enabled":true
},
"tooltip": {
    "headerFormat": "<b>{point.x}</b><br/>",
    "pointFormat": "{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}"
},
"plotOptions": {
    "column": {
        "stacking": "normal",
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "color": "white",
            "style": {
                "textShadow": "0 0 3px black"
            }
        }
    },
    "series": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "point": {
            "events": {
                "click": "function () {alert(y.value);}"
            }
        }
    }
},
"series": []
}
```

Below are the script tags that i am using

```
<script src="./resources/js/highstock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="./resources/js/highstock/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) your click event function - if you don't do it, you have a string instead of the function to be called on the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                console.log("this : ",this)
                console.log('this.y',this.y)
                    alert(this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can debug it by console.log.as deep 3015 jiddle is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is defined as

```
series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert(this.y); /*not y.value*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/085webv8/) demo

[Highcharts Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click)

Comment: i modified it to "this.y", but still i am getting a similar error called highstock.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: e.call is not a function

Comment: @ZEE can you add your fiddle . mine fiddle is working